# Is it okay to say Alhamdulillah on someone's death?

Tags: allah, forgiveness

One of my teachers died on a road accident. He was a really strict teacher. I said Alhamdulillah. I feel remorseful for saying that. I am really sorry for that. I want to ask forgiveness from Allah. Please guide me how to ask forgiveness?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it okay to say Alhamdulillah on someone's death?

As much as I know/presume: it is not OK (at least, at "most of times"), since Islam is the religion of blessing and don't approve so; presumably unless in some exception situations.

Otherwise, teachers are generally great humans who ... so, you'd better repeat phrases such as استغفرالله ربی و اتوب الیه and e.g. to donate charity by his side ... so, Allah will forgive you. Enshallah (God willing).